# Piezo connected to ESP32 - Why doesn't it kill the input?

Tags: analog, input, esp32, piezo

I have a ESP32, and a piezo disk connected as a sensor:

- Piezo - to GND
- Piezo + to Analog In
- 50K Resistor in parallel to piezo

My understandin is that the piezo generates a voltage when it is mechanically deformed either through vibrations (like sound) or through mechanical pressure onto it. The resistor is there to get rid of the charge after the fact, and avoid the analog input floating somewhere. The lower the resistor value, the less sensitive the system will be. In my case I chose a pretty low resistor value to catch only very loud noises (gun firing.) It works and all is well, but I would like to learn and understand one thing:

If the piezo is hit VERY hard, couldn't it theoretically generate high high voltages that are way beyond the 3.3V that the ESP32 can handle? If so, how can this voltage be limited, and why doesn't anyone limit it in any of the schematics I found online?

Comment: Most CMOS microcontrollers have clamp diodes on the inputs for ESD protection. If the current is limited to what those diodes can handle input voltage can not go beyond the rails by more then a diode drop.

Comment: @Unimportant *Most CMOS microcontrollers* You can safely assume that **ALL** CMOS microcontrollers have this ESD protection. Without ESD protection it is too easy to damage the transistors on the chip. The danger is also that you can damage a transistor but not notice it yet. Then you solder the MCU on a PCB which then fails after some time. No one want this to happen. Proper ESD protection will minimize this risk.

Comment: @OP: Do realize that using the internal ESD protection like this may cause issues in the long run as you do not know how well the internal ESD protection can handle this kind of abuse. There is a chance that this violates the maximum ratings of the IC, which are there to protect the ESD protection. If it were my design and it would need to be reliable I would add a clamping circuit so that I do not violate the MCU's maximum ratings.

Comment: If your piezo generates such high voltage, consider connecting it to a **digital input** rather than **analog ADC**. As others have suggested, a series resistor will help clip too-large swings. Digital inputs will allow multiple simultaneous input sampling, and respond far faster than any analog input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are such schematics that try to protect the input.

Often there are resistors in series and clamp diodes to prevent voltages from damaging the MCU input.